# which software is suitable for remote-desktop management?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet, remote-desktop

which software is suitable in ubuntu for remote desktop management using internet. not home network (LAN).

Comment: is the remote computer running windows or ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) is by far the best program for this, it is free for personal use and it has clients available for Windows, Mac, Linux and mobile devices. You can also set up remote access so that you don't have to be at the actual computer and "accept" the incoming connection.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps either of these will give you the answer.

1. http://www.mynitor.com/2010/02/07/15-remote-desktop-solutions-for-linux/
2. http://rdpdesk.com/

I can not comment any more. I did not feel the need to use any so far.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try team viewer. It's best when it comes to connect remote PCs through internet.

Comment: i used teamviewer in windows. but is it work in ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it does work in Linux. It runs within the packaged wine environment. So it's the same windows binaries.